# How to quit a plpgsql procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In my plpgsql procedure, I start with checking if primary key for the input table exists. If not I raise a notice and want to quit the procedure. Otherwise, I continue with the rest of procedure. I spent a bit of time searching online but no clear answer. Please note that I am referring to a procedure which doesn't return anything so I can't use RETURN.

Comment: Of course you can `RETURN`, you just wouldn't return a value. Other than that, you can of course wrap the rest of your procedure in an `IF` block (resp. put in the `ELSIF` of your existing check).

Comment: [Returning from a stored procedure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-PROCEDURE) in the postgres manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `return`.

```
create or replace procedure test(text)
language plpgsql as $$
begin
    raise notice '%', $1;
    return;
    raise notice 'never executed';
end $$;

call test('hello');

NOTICE:  hello
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test(text) line 3 at RAISE
CALL
```